# Can only connect one time to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I launched a new AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server t2.micro instance via the AWS console. I was able to successfully connect to the instance a single time using `ssh` on macOS Sierra 10.12.3:

```
$ ssh -i ./ubuntu-server-2-17-2017.pem ubuntu@ec2-55-555-555-555.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I try to connect a second time, I get a time out error:

```
$ ssh -i ./ubuntu-server-2-17-2017.pem ubuntu@ec2-55-555-555-555.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-55-555-555-555.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you stop and start the instance before attempting to connect the second time?

Comment: The IP changes if you stop and start the instance (not reboot). To prevent this, associate an elastic IP with the instance which doesn't change between boots.

Comment: @helloV When I stopped and started the instance, I was able to get another 2 or 3 logins (using the new Public DNS) to the instance and then the following error: `$ packet_write_wait: Connection to 55.555.55.555 port 22: Broken pipe`. Then the same error after that: `ssh: connect to host ec2-55-555-55-555.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out`.

Comment: @Borealis Try to log in, then log in many times in different session keeping the first one open until you're unable to log in. Check logs. 
Double-check IP and try to connect using IP. Create another instance and use it as a jump box to connect to the first instance using internal IP.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to check is that the IP address associated with the instance is still the same.

The other thing to look at, then, is the security group to see if your IP address (which maybe changed) is still allowed.